# Restricting Function Parameter Types with Class Decorator Both Args and KWargs

Tags: python, parameters

I wanted an easy-to-use decorator class that can be used to force certain parameters to be pre-defined types lest an error be raised. The issue is that I have to specify each variable twice, one for each args and one for kwargs. This is true even with default parameters, provided there is no single splat parameter in the original function.

Simplified:

```
class ParamConstraint:
    def __init__(self, *args, error=TypeError, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.error = error

    def __call__(self, function):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            for (arg, constraint) in zip(args, self.args):
                if not isinstance(arg, constraint):
                    raise self.error(
                        "Value '{}' is not of type '{}'.".format(arg, constraint.__name__)
                    )
            for kwarg in self.kwargs:
                if kwarg in kwargs:
                    assert isinstance(kwargs[kwarg], self.kwargs[kwarg])
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return __import__("functools").wraps(function)(wrap)
```

This is easy enough to use. Say I wanted a function that would multiply a number by 2, but I only want integers, not floats. I can use:

```
@ParamConstraint(int)
def foo(x):
    return x*2

print(foo(5))  # => prints 10
print(foo(x=5.0))  # => prints 10.0
print(foo(5.0))  # => raises TypeError
```

Now, I can prevent this by passing both positional and non-positional arguments into a function, but it gets very tedious after a while. For example, I'd have to write out 6 constraints for 3 parameters:

```
@ParamConstraint((int, float), int, FunctionType, value=(int, float), count=int, func=FunctionType):
def foo(value, count, func):
    for _ in range(count):
        value = func(value)
    return value
```

Ideally, I should be able to just pass it by KWarg and not provide any positional arguments. However, this does not work because I have no way of finding out what the positional arguments of the original function are. I have used the `inspect` module minorly to no avail.

How can I remediate this?